# What's the right HTTP status code when REST resource isn't there?

Tags: http-status-codes

I'm a bit confused on HTTP status code.  Let's say someone calls an endpoint like `.../person/15` but there isn't actually a person with identifier 15.

I was previously returning a 412, but as I read that status code closer that's supposed to be related to headers.

Comment: Check this out and you'll find good reads. http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203492/when-to-use-http-status-code-404-in-an-api

Comment: Can't imagine what somebody thought was so horrible about the question they had to downvote it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be 404 (Not Found). If you’re able to detect that the person has been deleted (and their id won’t be reused), use 410 (Gone).

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP status code you may want to use is `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`. There is also a very usefull list with all these codes:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes